# How to setup remote config in Alpine?

Tags: alpine-mail

I use Alpine to read Gmail. I have several Linux machines that I login to and I'd like to use [Alpine Remote Config](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/low-level.html#remote-config) so all settings can be downloaded to the machine I'm running Alpine on and importantly, my remote/Gmail address book is available. I'd appreciate if someone can point me to a set of instructions or confirm if this is even possible with Gmail.

If its not possible with Gmail, I was wondering if I could use a RPI as server to store those configs so clients that connect to the server can download the necessary files.

Update:
I tried this: `$ alpine -p "{mailserver.org:143/user=jimbob123/tls}remote_pinerc"` from [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alpine) and it didn't really work, perhaps Gmail needs to be setup first.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alpine -p "imap.gmail.com/notls/ssl/user=jimbob123}remote_pinerc"
```